# How to access an objects properties directly without using "For Each In"?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I'm using `FileSystemObject` to build an object for the contents of a folder.

```
Set fs = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fo = fs.GetFolder(server.MapPath("My_Folder"))
```

This folder should only contain one file. I can use `fo.files.count` to confirm this:

```
If fo.Files.Count = 1 Then ...
```

But how can I access the properties of that 1 file directly from the `fo` object without using a `for each in` loop? I know I can retrieve the filename of that one file using:

```
For Each x In fo.Files
  Response.write x.Name
Next
```

But why loop if there's just one file? Shouldn't it be possible to access the properties directly from the `fo` object?

```
Dim fs : Set fs = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim fo : Set fo = fs.GetFolder(server.MapPath("My_Folder"))

If fo.Files.Count = 1 Then
  response.write fo.Files(0).Name ' doesn't work
  response.write fo.Files.Item(0).Name ' doesn't work   
  response.write fo.Files.file(0).Name ' doesn't work   
  response.write fo.File(0).Name ' doesn't work
End If

Set fo = Nothing
Set fs = Nothing
```

I've tried many combinations, but I can't figure out how to access the `fo` object properties directly unless I use a `For Each In` loop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831890/how-to-get-collection-item-by-index

Comment: @montonero I did search for similar questions before posting, but didn't see that one. `The .Files collection can't be accessed by index, You need a For Each loop to fill a random access collection e.g. an Array`. Well that answers that then. Thanks for posting the link, this was bothering me all afternoon.